# Beyond Compare 4 as a Difftool for Git on Windows 10 Pro

Tags: git, windows-10, beyondcompare4

I am trying to setup Beyond Compare 4 (`v4.2.3`) as my `difftool` for Git (`v2.15.1.windows.2`) but I cannot get it to launch. I have followed the [instructions they've given](https://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs), but it just doesn't work!

My `.gitconfig` looks like this:

```
[diff]
    tool = bc3
[difftool "bc3"]
    path = c:/Program Files/Beyond Compare 4/bcomp.exe
[merge]
    tool = bc3
[mergetool "bc3"]
    path = c:/Program Files/Beyond Compare 4/bcomp.exe
```

When I run, the following:

```
git difftool src\CF1.Charles.Helpers\CF1.Charles.Helpers.csproj
```

Nothing happens! I just get the command prompt again.

What am I missing?

Comment: You have specified the `path` but you also need to specify the `cmd`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was Googling this very problem and came across this page.  It got me 90% of the way there, but the other answer given is for Beyond Compare 3 and the `$(cygpath -w $LOCAL)` didn't work.  I'm using git bash, so that may be the difference there.

Anyway, here's what works for me with BC4 and git bash.

```
[merge]
    tool = bc4
[mergetool "bc4"]
    cmd = \"C:\\Program Files\\Beyond Compare 4\\Bcompare.exe\" "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
[mergetool "vscode"]
    cmd = code --wait $MERGED
[diff]
    tool = bc4
[difftool "bc4"]
    cmd = \"C:\\Program Files\\Beyond Compare 4\\Bcompare.exe\" "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"
[difftool "vscode"]
    cmd = code --wait --diff $LOCAL $REMOTE
```

Note that I left my VS Code configuration in here too.  I haven't actually tried doing a merge with Beyond Compare yet.
But if you want to switch between VS Code and Beyond Compare, you just change the `tool =`  line to the one you want.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
[merge]
        tool = bc3
[mergetool "bc3"]
        cmd = \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Beyond Compare 3\\Bcomp.exe\" "$(cygpath -w $LOCAL)" "$REMOTE"
[diff]
        tool = bc3
[difftool "bc3"]
        cmd = \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Beyond Compare 3\\Bcomp.exe\" "$(cygpath -w $LOCAL)" "$REMOTE"
```

Comment: Are you sure? Cause this used to work before without having to do anything extra!

Comment: That's the congfiguration I have in my machine and works just fine for me.

Comment: Ok, I just tried (pointed path to my location), and again, nothing happens; same issue as before :(

Comment: The file I'm testing it on has already been staged (but not committed), it should still work right?

Comment: I think you have to use the `--cached` option as you'd do if you'd used the plain `git diff` command.